# Bluetooth Keyboard won't automatically connect

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, connection-issues, external-keyboard

I have a Logitech k810 Bluetooth keyboard, which can switch between 3 devices with corresponding buttons. I have it paired with my Windows 7 laptop, a Tablet, and an HTC Rezound with Andorid 4.0.3.

I can switch between Windows and my Android tablet with no issue. I just press the corresponding button on the keyboard and 2 seconds later I can type on either device.

When trying to switch to my phone, the keyboard LED blinks as it attempts to connect but never does. There is no indication on the phone. The keyboard's Bluetooth profile on the phone *is* activated (checkbox is checked). If I select the device in the Bluetooth device list, it says "Please press any key on your keyboard to reconnect.", but pressing keys does nothing.
[image]

It appears the only way to actually connect it is to press the conncect button on the keyboard and manually go to the phone's Bluetooth device profile options and click on the *already checked* checkbox for the keyboard input.
[image]

I imagine this would happen with my phone and any Bluetooth keyboard, which ruins the convenience of a keyboard at all.

Any clues as to the issue? I'd love to be able to just connect without spending 2 minutes doing so every time.

Comment: I see the same message when I tap my computer (!) in the list of Bluetooth devices on my HTC with Android 6. Why does it think my computer is a keyboard?